# Prove the existence of some weird family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Prove the existence of uncountable family $\{X_i \subseteq \mathbb{N}\}_{i \in \mathbb{R}}$ such that intersection of any $k$ sets from this family is infinite and intersection of any $k+1$ sets is finite. $k \ge 2$, $\mathbb{N}$ means natural numbers, $\mathbb{R}$ means real numbers.

Comment: A smaller family seems easy: Identify $\Bbb N$ with $\Bbb Q^{k+1}$ and let $X_i$ be the orthogonal space to a certain vector $v_i$. One must make sure though that the $v_i$ are in "general position" (no $k+1$ are linearly dependent).

Comment: Again, the "elementary" in the tag doesn't mean that the question is elementary, but rather the set theory is elementary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila tag description says "This tag is for elementary questions on set theory" but ok, probably your right.

Comment: Does your question for the tag description of the set theory tag?

Comment: I meant elementar-set-theory tag

Comment: So the family is dependent upon a fixed k? Cause if it were true for all k... it wouldn't be true for any k... right?

Comment: It's dependent of course. You mentioned Noah previous solution and you edited the comment.

Comment: Noah's answer to your f(x,y) = f(y,z) => x=y=z gave a link to a solution to a family just like this (only better).  Try that.

Comment: I dont see any link there. It's probably removed from there. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Actually this looks significantly harder than just building an almost disjoint family (although I'm sure you can construct these from almost disjoint families via some clever trick); right now, I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Belay that: I *think* I got it . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a construction which I think combines the cleanest elements of Noah's and Gro-Tsen's.

By applying bijections, we can use any sets $A,B$ with $|A| = |\mathbb{N}|$ and $|B| = |\mathbb{R}|$ in place of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the infinite rooted binary tree. Take $A$ to be the set of $k$-tuples of vertices in the tree, where we require the vertices in each $k$-tuple to all lie on the same level of the tree. Take $B$ to be the set of infinite rays in the tree which start at the root. These sets have the correct cardinalities.

For each ray $\rho$ in $B$, let $X_\rho$ be the set of $k$-tuples in $A$ which contain at least one element of $\rho$.

The intersection of any $k$ sets of this form is infinite, since on each level of the tree we can choose a $k$-tuple containing one vertex from each ray.

The intersection of any $k+1$ sets of this form is finite, since on some level of the tree, the $k+1$ rays must have all branched apart, so there is no $k$-tuple of vertices on that level or below which hits all $k+1$ rays.

Answer (score 3):

For each $\xi\colon \mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$, consider the set $X_\xi$ of functions $s\colon \{0,\ldots,N-1\} \to\{0,1\}$ where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and such that there exists $j\in\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ for which $s(ik+j)=\xi(i)$ for each $i$ such that $ik+j<N$ (roughly: the values of $s$ on some congruence class mod $k$ must be those given by $\xi$).

Given $k$ functions $\xi_j\colon \mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ (for $0\leq j<k$), we can find infinitely many $s$ in the intersection of the $X_\xi$, namely the retriction $\{0,\ldots,N-1\}$ for any $N$ of the function $ik+j \mapsto \xi_i(j)$.  Given at least $k+1$ of them, however, any way of assigning congruence classes mod $k$ to them will have two different $\xi$'s in the same class, so that there are only finitely many $N$'s up to which one can construct a function $s$ agreeing with the given $\xi$'s on those congruence classes.

This constructs for each $\xi \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ a set $X_\xi$ of finite binary sequences with the required intersection properties (any $\leq k$ of them have infinite intersection, any $\geq k+1$ of them have finite intersection).  Now it's just a matter of injecting the reals in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and injecting the set $\{0,1\}^*$ of finite binary sequences in the natural numbers.

(Reading Noah Schweber's solution, this one appears to be essentially equivalent, only using finite sequence approximations to infinite sequences instead of rational approximations to reals.  I wonder if very different constructions can be found.)

Comment: +1. I think this is probably a clearer argument than mine.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's a really silly way to do it:

A *$k$-Cauchy sequence* is a sequence of $k$-tuples $((x_1^1, . . . , x_k^1), (x_1^2, . . . , x_k^2), . . .)$ which is componentwise Cauchy - that is, for each $i$ the sequence $(x^1_i, x^2_i, x^3_i, . . . )$ is Cauchy. (If you think of a Cauchy sequence as approximating a real, think of a $k$-Cauchy sequence as approximating a $k$-tuple of reals.)

A *$k$-Cauchy sequence of rationals* is just a $k$-Cauchy sequence, all of whose terms are $k$-tuples of rationals.

OK, fix a bijection $f: \mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{N}$; and for each real $r$, fix a specific Cauchy sequence of rationals $C_r$ converging to $r$.
 Note that from this we can associate a $k$-Cauchy sequence of rationals $C_F$ to any $k$-tuple of reals $F$.

Now via $f$ we can identify initial segments of $k$-Cauchy sequences of rationals with natural numbers. (It's a bit messy, but oh well.) To the real $r$ we assign the set $A_r$ of **all naturals associated to initial segments of $k$-Cauchy sequences of rationals $C_F$ with $F\ni r$**, that is, $$A_r=\{code(\sigma): \sigma\prec C_F\mbox{ for some $F\ni r$ with $\vert F\vert=k$}\}$$ where "$code(\sigma)$" is the natural associated to $\sigma$.

Whew! Well, now, let's see that this satisfies the desired properties. The intersection of $k$-many $A_r$s is clearly infinite; the hard part is showing that the intersection of $(k+1)$-many $A_r$s is finite. This is a neat argument, which for now I'm going to leave as an exercise, with a hint:

HINT: Suppose $A_{r_1}\cap . . . \cap A_{r_{k+1}}$ is infinite. Then show that for some $i\le k$, infinitely many initial segments of the Cauchy sequences $C_{r_i}$ and $C_{r_{k+1}}$ are the same. What does this tell you about $r_i$ and $r_{k+1}$?

FURTHER HINT: To find the $i$ mentioned in the previous hint, look at $C_{(r_1, . . . , r_k)}$. Since the $r_i$s are disjoint, there's some $n$ such that $C_{r_i}(n)\not=C_{r_j}(n)$ for any $i<j\le k$ (why?). So look at the $n$th term of $C_{(r_1, . . . , r_k)}$. This is a $k$-tuple, and one of the elements of this $k$-tuple must be the length-$n$ initial segment of $C_{r_{k+1}}$ (why?) . . .

Comment: Note: A crucial aspect of this construction is that an element of $A_r$ represents an *initial segment* of a $k$-Cauchy sequence, not just a term in it.

Comment: In understanding this it is important to note that there is no upper bound on the lengths of the initial segments of the  sequences. Nice construction.Also works for k=1.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't exacly understand
"To the real $r$ we assign the set $A_r$ of all naturals associated to initial segments of k-Cauchy sequences"
how did you get this k-Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @NoahSchweber how exactly did you get this $F$ set for some $r$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber and what do you mean by "initial segment of k-Cauchy sequence"? How can we order those tuples? Just via bijection $\mathbb{Q}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and taking natural order in $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: @pingwindyktator Fix $r$. Let $S_r$ be the set of all $k$-tuples (note: $k$-tuples are *ordered*) containing $r$. Now, to each $k$-tuple of reals $(s_1, . . . , s_k)$ we associated the $k$-Cauchy sequence $((C_{s_1}(1), . . . , C_{s_k}(1)), (C_{s_1}(2), . . . , C_{s_k}(2)), (C_{s_1}(3), . . . , C_{s_k}(3)), . . .)$; an initial segment of this sequence is a finite sequence of the form $((C_{s_1}(1), . . . , C_{s_k}(1)), (C_{s_1}(2), . . . , C_{s_k}(2)), (C_{s_1}(3), . . . , C_{s_k}(3)), . . . (C_{s_1}(n), . . . , C_{s_k}(n)))$. (cont'd)

Comment: Such an initial sequence is a *finite sequence* of *finite tuples* of *rationals* - such an object can be coded by a single natural number: We have in the background some bijection from $\bigcup_{n, k\in\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{Q}^k)^n$ to $\mathbb{N}$. (It's not hard to come up with such a bijection.) Finally: to a real $r$ we associate the set of all codes for initial segments of $k$-Cauchy sequences corresponding to $k$-tuples of reals containing $r$. For instance, if $k=2$ this means all codes of $k$-Cauchy sequences assigned to tuples $(r, s)$ or $(s, r)$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Does this help?

Comment: @NoahSchweber so $A_r$ have to be set of all naturals associated to initial segments of ** all k-Cauchy sequences containing $r$ ** ?

Comment: @pingwindyktator Yes, that's right. (Well, not exactly right - $A_r$ is the set of all naturals associated to initial segments of all k-Cauchy sequences which converge to something including $r$. It's not that the sequence contains $r$, it's that $r$ is one of the $k$-many reals the sequence converges to.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber "containts" means exactly that in this case ;) Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34555/discussion-between-pingwindyktator-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I dont exactly understand "This is a k-tuple, and one of the elements of this k-tuple must be the length-n initial segment of C_{r_{k+1}} (why?) . . ". Also - can we talk in chat?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the other constructions but stated more cleanly. Consider a fixed $k\in\mathbb N.$

Let $S$ be the set of all infinite sequences of zeros and ones, and let $M=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}M_{k,n}$ where $M_{k,n}$ is the set of all $k\times n$ matrices of zeros and ones; thus $|S|=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb R|,\ |M|=\aleph_0=|\mathbb N|,$ and $|M_{k,n}|=2^{kn}$ is finite. Define a family $\{X_s\subseteq M\}_{s\in S}$ as follows: for $s\in S,$ let
$$X_s=\{A\in M:\text{ some row of }A\text{ is an initial segment of }s\}.$$
It is easy to see that, if $s_1,\dots,s_k,s_{k+1}$ are distinct elements of $S,$ then $X_{s_1}\cap\dots\cap X_{s_k}$ is infinite while $X_{s_1}\cap\dots\cap X_{s_k}\cap X_{s_{k+1}}$ is finite.